# @Watch not triggered

Tags: typescript, vue.js

so my hiearchy is set like this

Root

- App

  - TimelineItem

    - TimelineMetadata

where

in app.vue
on mounted I do some http requests and on getting and processing the data I populate a timeline var

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="loading" v-show="loading">Loading ...</div>
    <table class="timeline">
        <TimelineItem v-for="event in timeline" :key="event.id" :item="event" :players="players" :match="match"></TimelineItem>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>


export default class App extends Vue {
  ... 

  public timeline: any[] = [];

  public mounted() {
    ...
    if (!!this.matchId) {
      this._getMatchData();
    } else {
      console.error('MatchId is not defined.  ?matchId=....');
    }
  }

  private _getMatchData() {
    axios.get(process.env.VUE_APP_API + 'match-timeline-events?filter=' + JSON.stringify(params))
      .then((response) => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.timeline = [];
        this.timeline = response.data;
  }

...
}
```

Then in my TimelineItem I have this:

```
<template>
  <tr>
    <td class="time">
      ...
      <TimelineItemMetadata :item="item" :match="match"></TimelineItemMetadata>

    </td>
  </tr>
</template>

....

@Component({
  components: {
    ...
  },
})
export default class TimelineItem extends Vue {
  @Prop() item: any;
  @Prop() match: any;
  @Prop() players: any;
}
</script>
```

And then, in my TimelineItemMetadata:

```
<template>
  <div>
    TEST1
    {{item}}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop, Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({})
export default class TimelineItemMetadata extends Vue {

  @Prop() item: any;
  @Prop() match: any;


  @Watch('match') onMatchChanged() {
    console.log('TEST');
  }
  @Watch('item') onItemChanged() {
    console.log('ITEM', this.item);
  }

  public mounted() {
    console.log('timeline metadata item component loaded');
  }

}
</script>
```

The item and match **@Watch** are **NOT** getting triggered but with Vue-devtools it says there is data... and it prints out... so why my @Watch is not triggered?

Comment: Maybe is just an issue with the copy/paste, but in your `TimelineItem` you're not setting the `TimelineItemMetada` in the `@Component` components option. Also, in your `TimelineItemMetadata` there is a typo defining the `onMathcChanged` function (which should be unrelated with your issue tho)

Comment: yeah, I am including all the components, hence the TimelineItemMetadata is showing and displaying the {{item}} .... just the @Watch is not triggering... thanks for the headsup for the typos... but yeah, it is unrelated, not solving the problem :/ been on this for hours now... cannot solve it :'(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, it seems that `match` and `item` props of the `TimelineItemMetadata` property doesn't change over time: they are just set by the `App` component when it gets mounted.

[As I read here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/watchers-not-triggered-on-initialization/12475), it seems that you need to pass an explicit `immediate` param to a watcher to make it trigger **the first time a prop changes.**.

So, I guess you should do:

```
// note typo is fixed
@Watch('match', {immediate: true}) onMatchChanged() {
  console.log('TEST');
}
@Watch('item', {immediate: true})) onItemChanged() {
  console.log('ITEM', this.item);
}
```

Comment: ow YESSS! it is working... like a charm... THANKS a LOT! you are a life saver!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is having the same error as me...

I wasted hours because I was resetting the state with a new instance of the state object (Wrong), instead of its properties (Correct).

So, do not overwrite your state object with a new one. But, change its properties.

```
export interface ISample {
    property1?: string;
    property2?: string;
}

export interface SampleState {
    current: ISample;
}

function getDefaultState (): SampleState {
    return {
        current: {
            property1: undefined,
            property2: undefined
        }
    }
}

export const state = getDefaultState

export const mutations: MutationTree<SampleState> = {
    setValue (state, value: ISample) {
        state.current.property1 = value?.property1
        state.current.property2 = value?.property1
    },

    reset (state) { // Correct
        state.current.property1 = undefined
        state.current.property2 = undefined
    },

    reset2 (state) { // Wrong! After resetting @Watch stopped working,
        state.current = getDefaultState().current
    }
}

export const actions: ActionTree<SampleState, {}> = {
    setValue ({ commit }, value: ISample) {
        commit('setValue', value)
    },

    reset ({ commit }) {
        commit('reset')
    }
}

export const getters: GetterTree<SampleState, {}> = {
    property1: (store) => {
        return store.current.property1
    },

    property2: (store) => {
        return store.current.property2
    }
}
```